# How to fix "qemu-system-x86_64: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvirglrenderer.so.0: undefined symbol: drmPrimeHandleToFD"?

Tags: debian, kernel, qemu

I want to run `qemu` on Debian Buster, and have therefore installed the `qemu-system-x86_64` package.

The issue is that when I run:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -m 128M \
    -cpu kvm64,+smep,+smap \
    -kernel vmlinuz \
    -initrd initramfs.cpio.gz \
    -hdb flag.txt \
    -snapshot \
    -nographic \
    -monitor /dev/null \
    -no-reboot \
    -append "console=ttyS0 kaslr kpti=1 quiet panic=1" \
```

I get the following error:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvirglrenderer.so.0: undefined symbol: drmPrimeHandleToFD
```

How can I fix this error?

According to `apt`, I've the latest version of `libvirglrenderer0` and there are no versions available in `debian-backports`.

Versions:

```
qemu-system-x86/stable,stable,now 1:3.1+dfsg-8+deb10u8 amd64 [installed]
libvirglrenderer0/stable,now 0.7.0-2 amd64 [installed]
```

Debian:

```
uname -a
Linux debian-parallels 4.19.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Update:

```
$ nm -D  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvirglrenderer.so.0 | grep drm
                 U drmPrimeHandleToFD
$ ldd  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvirglrenderer.so.0
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffedad5f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0d0bed8000)
    libgbm.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (0x00007f0d0bcd3000)
    libepoxy.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007f0d0bba1000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f0d0ba60000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0d0ba3f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0d0b87e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0d0c0ee000)
    libPrlDRI.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libPrlDRI.so.1 (0x00007f0d0b581000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0d0b3fd000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0d0b3e3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0d0b3de000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f0d0b3b4000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f0d0b1ae000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f0d0afa8000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f0d0af8e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f0d0af84000)
```

Update 1:

*Before and after installing Parallels Tools*:

[image]

Comment: The symbol is provided by `libdrm.so.2`, from the `libdrm2` package; what version of that do you have?

Comment: Why would you want to delete it? I don’t get the error you have, which is how I was able to figure out where the symbol comes from — `nm -D` could find it. You have the same versions of the libraries as I do, which suggests that some other library is being loaded instead. What does `ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvirglrenderer.so.0` say?

Comment: Yes, many packages depend on `libdrm2` and would be uninstalled along with it. `for file in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*.so*; do if nm -D "$file" | grep -q drmPrimeHandleToFD; then echo "$file"; nm -D "$file" | grep drmPrimeHandleToFD; fi; done` shows all libraries requiring or declaring `drmPrimeHandleToFD` (look for `T` for the declarations). Do you know where `libPrlDRI.so.1` comes from? The Debian `libvirglrenderer.so.0` doesn’t require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign that something is amiss is the

```
libPrlDRI.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libPrlDRI.so.1 (0x00007f0d0b581000)
```

line in `ldd`’s output: there’s no such library in Debian, so a library requiring it can’t come from a Debian package.

If `libvirglrenderer.so.0` library isn’t the version provided by Debian,

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libvirglrenderer0
```

would fix that; but apparently that’s not the issue here.

`libPrlDRI.so.1` comes from Parallel Tools; that ships a number of replacement libraries: `libEGL.so.1`, `libgbm.so.1`, and `libGL.so.1`, along with two Parallels-specific libraries, `libPrlDRI.so.1` and `libPrlWl.so.1`. The guilty party here is probably `libgbm.so.1`: QEMU requires that library, and if it loads Parallels’ version (either through `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or updated `ld.so` configuration), it ends up loading `libPrlDRI.so.1` *instead* of `libdrm.so.2`.

To fix that, you should be able to override the override:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 qemu-system-x86_64 ...
```

Comment: It seems the PrlDRI library comes from Parallels, perhaps something else is happening here (guest integration of some sort).

Comment: It seems that `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libPrlDRI.so.1` is associated with Parallels, the VM engine running my Debian installation

Comment: I just tried to `curl -XGET http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/virglrenderer/libvirglrenderer0_0.7.0-2_amd64.deb -O` to get the Debian version of `libvirglrenderer0`, and `ldd` still shows `libPrlDRI.so.1` as a dependency, so your hypothesis that `libvirglrenderer.so.0`is not the version provided by Debian is incorrect. **Do you know how `libPrlDRI.so.1` can take precedence over `libdrm.so.2`**?

Comment: `libPrlDRI.so.1` only takes precedence over `libdrm.so.2` after Parallels Tools is installed into the guest

Comment: See the update.

Comment: When I link against a dynamic library, then the name of that library is recorded in the binary, not just the symbols' name. Thus, I don't understand why `libvirglrenderer.so.0` doesn't use `libdrm.so.2` for resolving the  `drmPrimeHandleToFD` symbol, and that `libPrlDRI.so.1` somehow swaps place with `libdrm.so.2`.

Comment: `libvirglrenderer.so.0` itself doesn’t have a dependency on `libdrm.so.2`, it pulls it in through `libgbm.so.1`. Since Parallels’ `libgbm.so.1` doesn’t depend on `libdrm.so.2`, it doesn’t get loaded. You should find the `ld.so` configuration in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` along with `/etc/ld.so.conf`. To set `LD_PRELOAD` just for `qemu-system-x86_64`, an alias would work for interactive use, but won’t help with scripts...

Comment: So, although `libvirglrenderer.so.0` uses `libdrm.so.2` functionality, it doesn't depend on `libdrm.so.2` itself? I guess I will add `LD_PRELOAD` to individual commands, since a system-wide `LD_PRELOAD` may probably break things.